# UWP - Google Analytics - change trackingid at run time

Tags: google-analytics, uwp

I have and APP. Many customers use this APP.
I'd like to have an Google Trackingid for any Costumer.
Now i'd write my tracking id into my  Analytics.xml

I use 
xmlns="http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/ns/easytracker"

When in my code write

GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SetCustomDimension(1, "Title")
 GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SetCustomDimension(2, "ID")
 GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("Book")

I can't change TrackingId ...is possible to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, i had to change SDK
Now i use UWP.SDKforGoogleAnalytics.managed and i had wrote these rows

Dim _TrakerId As String = "UA-XXXX0-0"

Dim MyTraker As GoogleAnalytics.Tracker = GoogleAnalytics.AnalyticsManager.Current.CreateTracker(_TrakerId)
MyTraker.ScreenName = "Images"

Dim Hit = GoogleAnalytics.HitBuilder.CreateScreenView.Build

MyTraker.Send(Hit)

All work good... BUT... now i'd like to use Custom dimensions.
Can anyone hel me ??